# Why would someone blow the shofar from a hospital?

Tags: shofar

This evening around sunset someone blew a shofar from the top of the parking garage of the hospital across the street from my house.  It’s not the month of Elul now, so what is the reason?

(I’m not Jewish so there may well be something obvious I’m missing.  My best guess from google was a folk tradition to induce labor.)

Comment: Maybe it was a funny car horn sound? How do you know it was a shofar?

Comment: I could see the person blowing it in profile as well as hearing it.  It was definitely made from a spiral animal horn.

Comment: Birth of a baby?